# Which thread executes the Registered Action

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

In the codebehind of my MainPage I register for specific messages like so:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<String>(this, Notifications.ShowAlert, ShowAlertAction);
```

As you can imagine the `ShowAlertAction` does some UI work (pops up a child window in this case)

My concern is that it could happen that a message may be sent from a non-UI thread.  When the message is sent is it executed on the thread that does the sending or the thread that did the registering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Messenger does not dispatch to a different thread. So this is correct, the action is executed on the sender's thread, which can cause a cross thread exception. To avoid this, the recommended way is to use the DispatcherHelper class to send the message on the main thread even if your sender is running on a background thread.

Some other frameworks do the dispatching automatically (for example Prism) but the API is complex and confusing. I preferred a straightforward approach.

Cheers
Laurent